# launching a program with playlist launches another program instead

Tags: batch-file

I have this bit of code that I am trying to launch the playlist with. what keeps happening is that `foobar2000` opens the playlist instead. how do I force it to use a program?

```
start /d "c:\program files\mpc-hc\mpc-hc64.exe" "%temp%\hoard.m3u"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment as an answer.

Given what you intend to do, I would not expect that the current working directory would need to be that which holds the executable.

The following syntax would therefore make more sense:

```bat
Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\mpc-hc\mpc-hc64.exe" "%temp%\hoard.m3u"
```

Answer (score 0):

`/D` sets the working folder instead of the program to run - see `help start`.
Try
`start /d "c:\program files\mpc-hc\" "c:\program files\mpc-hc\mpc-hc64.exe" "%temp%\hoard.m3u"`

Comment: Because you've already defined the working directory there'd be no need to provide the full path to the executable. Your suggested syntax would be `Start /D "%ProgramFiles%\mpc-hc" mpc-hc64.exe "%temp%\hoard.m3u"`. I would not expect that the current working directory would need to be set as that holding the executable though so perhaps the following would be better, `Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\mpc-hc\mpc-hc64.exe" "%temp%\hoard.m3u"`.

Comment: the last suggestion by compo works, all the other methods still open foobar.